# Is a monotone map between sets always continuous?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, lattice-orders

[Isabelle](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/) says yes, but I am not really convinced. Given a map $f$ such that for all sets $A, B$ $A \subseteq B$ implies $f(A) \subseteq f(B)$, then is it always the case that $\bigcup_i f(S_i) = f(\bigcup_i S_i)$? In case it is, why? In case it isn't, where is the error in the next lemma that Isabelle proves?

```
lemma "(∀ P . ∀ Q . P ⊆ Q ⟶ f`P ⊆ f`Q) ⟹ 
       (f ` (UN x : A . B x) = (UN x : A . f`(B x)))"
by auto
```

Comment: Are you leaving off any conditions?  Surjectivity, say?  Otherwise...let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, with $f(x)=x$, for $x<0$ and $f(x)=x+1$ for $x≥0$.

Comment: @lulu I think the OP is using a different notion of 'continuous' than the topological one.

Comment: @Hayden  Ok...what notion would that be?

Comment: @lulu: Presumably the one defined in the question: that $f$ commutes with unions.

Comment: @lulu In order theory, a function $f: P \to Q$ is continuous when given any directed subset $A$ of $P$ then $f(\sup A) = \sup f[A]$.  The OP seems to care specifically about the case of ring of sets (or at least a directed subset of one), so the sups are now unions.

Comment: @Hayden  Thanks.  New definition for me, good way to start the morning!

Comment: You need to note the difference between what you wrote in the question and what you wrote in the title.

In general, set-valued functions need not be continuous. However, if you have $f\colon X\to Y$, and you look at the map induced by the "direct image" from $\mathcal P(X)$ to $\mathcal P(Y)$, then this map is indeed always continuous.

Comment: @AsafKaragila you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $U=\bigcup_iS_i$ and $V=\bigcup_if[S_i]$; we want to show that $f[U]=V$. For each $i$ we have $S_i\subseteq U$, so $f[S_i]\subseteq f[U]$, and hence $V\subseteq f[U]$. On the other hand, if $x\in U$, then $x\in S_i$ for some $I$, so $f(x)\in f[S_i]\subseteq V$, and therefore $f[U]\subseteq V$.